# Typeahead using NPM and MVC Core in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, asp.net-core-mvc, typeahead

I've entered the brave new world of MVC core and using NPM to get various JavaScript packages. However, I've hit a problem which I'm not entirely sure what the best option to solve is. Just to set the scene, I've got a gulpfile which is copying JS from various NPM packages in my project (such as jQuery and bootstrap etc...) to the 'wwwroot/lib' folder.

I now want to add a typeahead 'autocomplete' search box to a particular view, so I added typeahead to the package.json file and updated my gulpfile to copy the additional *.js files to 'wwwroot/lib'. All fine so far, the problem is when I debug my project and open that particular page I get an error where the typeahead.js file has some code at the beginning:-

```
require('xtend')
```

I wasn't aware of this command in JavaScript, but a quick search on the internet reveals this is part of JS when run on 'node' or node.js?

I have not used 'node' before (yes, ignoring the fact I'm using NPM to get packages - I only ended up doing that due to a Visual Studio bug in how Bower works) so the question is how do I now get (this particular) typeahead to run within a browser? So I figure options are:-

1) just manually download typeahead instead - but is that not defeating the point of having all these package managers in the first place?

2) start using Bower again (don't think the 'version' bug has been fixed yet)

3) use something to 'fake' the node 'require' commands so that it will work in browser

4) something else...

I've seen a few things that may solve this problem on the internet, but I didn't want to spend ages sorting out a fix which may be the complete wrong way of doing it. Has anyone any suggestions for the best route to follow?

Answer (score 0):

Scratch that, I found another typeahead package on NPM called 'typeahead.js' instead of 'typeahead' and this is just standard JS no NODE stuff. Works perfectly in browser